# Data sets and problems for learning hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

I'd like to get some real practice with hypothesis testing that is above what's in textbooks (plug and chug, usually). I was hoping someone could suggest some good data sets and problems to work on. Problems that I could show others that I've worked on. Along those lines, I'd very much appreciate any top notch references on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to form your hypotheses before seeing any of the actual data.  These hypotheses come from some sort of conceptual frame work.  Your best bet may be to form a hypothesis on a topic of interest to you and then try to find a data set to test that hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, but if there are good practice datasets out there, then you may as well go about forming your arbitrary hypothesis in a way that's relevant to them. I mean, there's not much worth in forming a hypothesis about the length of unicorn horns, is there? Doesn't mean you have to look at the data first.

Answer (score 4):

R has [a whole bunch of datasets built in](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) - they're used by all the examples for each function. Some are quite detailed, and you could do some really interesting stuff with them. The [Quick-R site](http://www.statmethods.net/) uses these datasets (the cars set especially) for most of their examples.